# Can you define a vector space in terms of a pre-existing projective space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition, projective-geometry, projective-space

Projective spaces are usually defined as the quotient of a vector space (by the equivalence relation that identifies collinear vectors). However, in my opinion, projective spaces seem intuitively less structured and more primitive than vector spaces. Is there a way to reverse the order of definition?

Projective spaces can be defined axiomatically (albeit in a more geometric way than vector spaces). Can you extract the structure of a vector space from an underlying projective space?

Comment: The complement of a hyperplane in a projective space is an affine space, and once you fix a point an affine space can be made into vector space. One ocn reconstruct the underlying field from geometrical constructions on the projective space. All this is **a lot** of work, and it would be more or less absurd to use it as the way to introduce vector spaces.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to work the details of this construction on my own. Of course it does not make sense pedagogically. A projective space is a more abstract notion. But it is fun to think about it this way. When I say "intuitively less structured", I certainly do not mean intuitively clear but, rather, more mathematically primitive, in the same way that a group can be thought of as less structured than a ring.

Answer (score 1):

The axioms of vector spaces usually talk about both the vector space itself, and the underlying scalar field, and the interaction between these two. So if you start off with a projective space, you'll need to extract a field from that first. I don't know about higher dimensions, but in the case of the plane, this is possible if and only if the theorem of Pappos holds in that projective plane. Which is not true in all projective planes. A key ingredient for the construction of a field from geometric facts are the constructions described by von Staudt which translate algebraic operations like addition and multiplication into geometric configurations. Once you have the field, it should be possible to work out the vector axioms for an arbitrarily chosen origin and a likewise arbitrarily chosen line at infinity. I don't have details on that.